# having problem with storing and getting image in mongoDb with multer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, multer

This is my router file!

```
router.post('/add', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    var img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    var encode_image = img.toString('base64');

    const image = new Image({
        image: Buffer.from(encode_image, 'base64'),
        contentType: req.file.mimetype
    })

    image.save()
         .then(img => {
             res.json(img.id)
         })
         .catch(err => res.json(err))

})
// 5e252bd7e4eaa9478c019f02
```

My schema for image upload

```
// Create Image Schema
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    image: {
        type: Buffer
    },
    contentType: {
        type: String
    },
    uploaded: {
        type: Date,my 
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

But after being uploading image to db my database

[image: Image of record in collection]

but when I try to retrieve it as:

```
router.get('/photo/:id', (req, res) => {
    var filename = req.params.id;

    Image.findOne({'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(filename) }, (err, result) => {

        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log(result)

       res.contentType(result.contentType);
       res.send(result.image.buffer)


      })
    })
```

I get a black screen without the image,
I referred [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088) for making the file upload.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I resolved the error by doing so :-=
changing

```
 res.send(result.image.buffer)
```

To

```
 res.send(new Buffer.from(result.image.buffer, 'base64'))
```

I dont know why this worked ! If anyone know kindly let me know . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It look's like problem with storing image to database

```
 const image = new Image({
        image: new Buffer.from(encode_image, 'base64'), // pass new object of Buffer with your image 
        contentType: req.file.mimetype
    })
```

Comment: I tried that it is still showing a black image on webpage! I am not able to resolve the issue till now.

Comment: link to output ;- https://gist.github.com/sudipt1999/4cd3416c63c5f30c4f81e18b88c60761